# jQuery replacewith varibles not getting replaced on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

On dropdown change the variable val is not getting changed in the replacewith. It is still set to the initial value but not getting updated.

alert(val) does give the correct value.
delete val does not help either.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#answerDropdown").change(function() {
      var val = $(this).val();
      if (val != '') {
        $("#filler").replaceWith('<div id="replaced"> ' + val +  '</div>');
        alert(val);
        delete val;
      }
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfrtjL2h/3/)

Comment: any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: It works for me, but only once, since it removes the target div on the first go.  Not sure what your intention with `delete val` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is after the first change you are REPLACING div with id='filler'

Therefore 2nd and subsequent onchange there will not be an element with id='filler' - so that code just doesn't run

you can do this instead

```
$("#filler").html('<div id="replaced"> ' + val +  '</div>');
```

This will result in the filler div having an inner div

or

```
$("#filler").replaceWith('<div id="filler"> ' + val +  '</div>');
```

which is identical to

```
$("#filler").text(val);
```